# How to save Id/server id to attachment object?

Tags: c#, outlook, ms-office, vsto

Is there anyway to save ID to attachment object?
 if no 
Is there anyway to get unique id from attachment object?

The problem is all attachments will upload to server, i need to check if there are any new attachment added to add to server "i can catch add event so it's fine" or if the file removed i need to know the related server id to delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `PR_COMMENT` MAPI property to store your custom information. You can get/set that property using `Attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty/SetProperty`. `PR_COMMENT DASL` name is `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x3004001F".`